# border radius of box

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, border-radius

i want to change the border raius of the dropdown box but i'm unable to target the exact tag by css

[image]

also the border radius of the button when on hover

[image]

and when i hover one of the links, the dropdown button acts as i hover above it

[image]

i tried alot of tags but i cannot reach the correct one, please support me

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
dropbtn{
  border-radius: 15px;
}
</style>
</head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body bgcolor="gray">

<div class="w3-container">
  <h2>Clickable Dropdown</h2>
  <p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
  <div style="border-radius: 25px;" class="w3-dropdown-click">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" id="clickme" class="w3-button w3-black" style="border-radius: 25px;">Click Me!</button>
    <div id="Demo" style="border-radius: 25px;" class="dropbtn w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-border">
      <a href="#" class="dropbtn w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="dropbtn w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#" class="dropbtn w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("Demo");
  if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
    x.className += " w3-show";
  } else { 
    x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed the class selector `.` in your style tag

```
<style>
.dropbtn{
  border-radius: 15px;
}
</style>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If it is just a typo I think it would be better this to be submitted as a comment and not as an answer.

Comment: oh ok, I'm a newbie here :)

Comment: Don't worry, good luck on the platform!